# Azure Backup on Windows Server 2012 Essentials - cannot register server

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012, azure

I'm trying to set up Azure Backup on a new Server 2012 Essentials machine.

I've created the backup Vault, downloaded the Essentials version of the Azure Backup module, and installed it.

On this server, I can log into the Azure management portal no problemo.

Now, when go to "register this server for backup" in the "Azure Backup" section, I cannot log in using my Azure credentials. The first few times I tried, I just got a message along the lines of "we can't find an account matching these credentials" (yes I checked them, several times).

Today I try again, having made no changes, and get a script error from the popup dialog. From what I can make out, it looks like jQuery cannot be loaded.

[image: screenshot of script error]

I've added *.windowsazure.com (among others) to trusted sites, tried turning off the firewall, no dice. Nothing in the eventlog either.

Anyone else seen this behaviour ?

Comment: That script error usually shows up in cases where the browser control couldn't load javascript files from a CDN. Does your server's traffic traverse a proxy? It may be that the proxy either has a bad version of the file or is blocking access.

Comment: Thanks for responding Simon, I will check. I don't think it runs through a proxy. It's strange that I can log in using a browser but not via the Server 2012 dashboard. Will update and let you know.

Comment: Check IE security settings for the server. Non-admin users might need a tweak to get it to work (cross-site security could be an issue) - maybe the default security setting is stopping the browser control from working properly.

Comment: OK - adding *.microsoftonline.com to trusted sites fixed the scripting issue, no idea why it didn't occur before but - I am back to being stuck on it refusing my credentials. Used Wireshark to see what was going back and forth and it's talking to secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com for authentication. Added this to trusted sites, checked IE security settings, added a manual firewall rule to allow inbound/outbound port 80/443 for the dashboard - still the same. Aaarrrgh!

Comment: did you set the setting to intranet compatiility off? check the browser default setting for running compat mode

Comment: OK after a lot of swearing and analysis, I have come to the conclusion that the plugin module for the Dashboard doesn't want to work. If I use the standalone Azure Backup program, everything works fine. Really not sure why :\